# Combining Sorted Lists working 7/10 times

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote some code to combine two sorted arrays into one sorted array. I'm doing it purely for learning purposes. I wrote my own code (without looking up how it is done) and have encountered an odd error. My code works about 7/10 of the time, that is it is pushing the two sorted arrays into one sorted array properly 7/10 times it is ran (on average). When it does not sort properly it is always towards the end of the array where numbers are not in proper order.

Here is an incorrect sample output (using random numbers to populate to arrays): `[3, 16, 19, 24, 27, 33, 35, 41, 52, 55, 59, 67, 74, 77, 78, 79, 84, 87, 89, 91, 91, 92, 87, 92]`

As you can see the error (87) is in the incorrect position.

Here is another sample: `[0, 4, 7, 8, 10, 11, 15, 16, 24, 25, 31, 32, 38, 54, 58, 62, 63, 66, 67, 70, 75, 80, 62, 80]`

And another: `[12, 14, 15, 25, 32, 34, 37, 42, 46, 48, 53, 54, 55, 58, 59, 60, 65, 66, 69, 70, 72, 79, 70, 79]`

Another: `[4, 25, 25, 27, 30, 42, 42, 43, 49, 49, 58, 62, 63, 63, 64, 64, 68, 69, 74, 63, 64, 64, 69, 74]`

I just keep running it and around 3/10 of the time I get an unsorted output. Can anyone tell me what part of my code is causing this? Thanks!

```
public static int[] mergeSortedLists(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
    {
        int[] sortedArr = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];
        int n = 0, m = 0, independentCounter = 0;

        while (n < arr1.length || m < arr2.length)
        {
            if (n != arr1.length && m != arr2.length)
            {

                if (arr1[n] < arr2[m])
                {
                    sortedArr[independentCounter] = arr1[n++];
                }
                else
                {

                    sortedArr[independentCounter] = arr2[m++];
                }
            }
            else if (n == arr1.length)
            {
                copy(m, independentCounter, arr2, sortedArr);
                break;
            }
            else if (m == arr2.length)
            {
                copy(n, independentCounter, arr2, sortedArr);
                break;
            }
            independentCounter++;
        }

        return sortedArr;
    }

    public static void copy(int copyFromUnsortedIndex, int copyToSortedIndex, int[] unsortedArr, int[] sortedArr)
    {

        while (copyToSortedIndex < sortedArr.length && copyFromUnsortedIndex < unsortedArr.length)
        {

            sortedArr[copyToSortedIndex++] = unsortedArr[copyFromUnsortedIndex++];

        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to have some realistic input arrays, not to mention a `main` function, so we don't have to create these things in order to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both of your `copy()` calls, you specify `arr2`:

```
        else if (n == arr1.length)
        {
            copy(m, independentCounter, arr2, sortedArr);
            break;
        }
        else if (m == arr2.length)
        {
            copy(n, independentCounter, arr2, sortedArr);
            break;
        }
```

You mean `arr1` for the case where `n` is used as the source index:

```
        else if (m == arr2.length)
        {
            copy(n, independentCounter, arr1, sortedArr); // <- arr1
            break;
        }
```

The reason this only tends to affect numbers at the end of the arrays is that these cases don't happen until one of the inputs has been fully consumed, which generally happens at the end. You're essentially copying bits of the wrong array to the very end when `arr2` is shorter than `arr1`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer, and @JasonC already addresses a significant problem. Regardless, this should help both you and those trying to solve it. It's a fully working class with one demo-input, a testing (`main`) function, and a bunch of debugging output:

(The only obvious problem I see is that the last item in the result-array is effectively being duplicated, because the truly-supposed-to-be-final-item is never put in the result array.)

```
   import  java.util.Arrays;
/**
   <P>{@code java SortTwoArrays}</P>
 **/
public class SortTwoArrays  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      test(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 99, 100, 120, 10000},
           new int[]{35, 36, 37, 49, 51, 59, 1000, 2000, 2001, 9999});
   }
   private static final void test(int[] ints_a, int[] ints_b)  {
      System.out.println("A: " + Arrays.toString(ints_a));
      System.out.println("B: " + Arrays.toString(ints_b));
      System.out.println("Merged: " + Arrays.toString(mergeSortedLists(ints_a, ints_b)));
      System.out.println();
   }
   public static int[] mergeSortedLists(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)  {
      int[] sortedArr = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];
      int n = 0, m = 0, independentCounter = 0;

      while (n < arr1.length || m < arr2.length)  {
         if (n != arr1.length && m != arr2.length)  {
            if (arr1[n] < arr2[m])  {
               sortedArr[independentCounter] = arr1[n++];
System.out.println("1. " + Arrays.toString(sortedArr));
            }  else  {
               sortedArr[independentCounter] = arr2[m++];
System.out.println("2. " + Arrays.toString(sortedArr));
            }
         }  else if (n == arr1.length)  {
            copy(m, independentCounter, arr2, sortedArr);
System.out.println("3. " + Arrays.toString(sortedArr));
            break;
         }  else if (m == arr2.length)  {
            copy(n, independentCounter, arr2, sortedArr);
System.out.println("4. " + Arrays.toString(sortedArr));
            break;
         }
         independentCounter++;
      }
      return sortedArr;
   }

   public static void copy(int copyFromUnsortedIndex, int copyToSortedIndex, int[] unsortedArr, int[] sortedArr)  {
      while (copyToSortedIndex < sortedArr.length && copyFromUnsortedIndex < unsortedArr.length)  {
         sortedArr[copyToSortedIndex++] = unsortedArr[copyFromUnsortedIndex++];
System.out.println("5. Copied  sortedArr[" + (copyToSortedIndex - 1) + "] (" + sortedArr[(copyToSortedIndex - 1)] + ") --> unsortedArr[" + (copyFromUnsortedIndex - 1) + "] (" + unsortedArr[(copyFromUnsortedIndex - 1)] + ")");
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java SortTwoArrays
A: [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 99, 100, 120, 10000]
B: [35, 36, 37, 49, 51, 59, 1000, 2000, 2001, 9999]
1. [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1. [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1. [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1. [1, 2, 3, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 37, 49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 37, 49, 51, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 37, 49, 51, 59, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 37, 49, 51, 59, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 37, 49, 51, 59, 99, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 37, 49, 51, 59, 99, 100, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 37, 49, 51, 59, 99, 100, 120, 1000, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 37, 49, 51, 59, 99, 100, 120, 1000, 2000, 0, 0, 0]
2. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 37, 49, 51, 59, 99, 100, 120, 1000, 2000, 2001, 0, 0]
2. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 37, 49, 51, 59, 99, 100, 120, 1000, 2000, 2001, 9999, 0]
5. Copied  sortedArr[19] (9999) --> unsortedArr[9] (9999)
4. [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 37, 49, 51, 59, 99, 100, 120, 1000, 2000, 2001, 9999, 9999]
Merged: [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 35, 36, 37, 49, 51, 59, 99, 100, 120, 1000, 2000, 2001, 9999, 9999]
```

Answer (score 0):

The general concept of the merge sort is "divide and conquer" you should concatenate the two array in one first time and I think is better to use Integer object than an int variable, because you will able to use comparable function.

Exemple : (5.compateTo(6) > 0) will return false, because 5 is not greater than 6.

### Concatenate method

There is an easy way to do it.

```
Integer[] conca(Integer[] array1, Integer[]array2)
{
    Integer[] tempo = new Integer[array1.length + array2.length];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
    {
        tempo[i] = array1[i];
    }
    
    for(int i = array1.length; i < array2.length; i++)
    {
        tempo[i] = array2[i];
    }
    
    return tempo;
}
```

Now you have a simple array to sort and you can sort it with a merge sort algorithm routine.

### Merge Sort

This is your public method calling a private methode with different parameters.
Merge sort needs a second array that contain your sorted array.

```
public static void mergeSort(Integer[] a)
{
    Integer[] tempo = new Integer[a.length];
    mergeSort(a, tempo, 0, a.length - 1);
}
```

Now the private method.

```
/**
 * Internal method that makes recursive calls
 * @param a an array of Comparable items
 * @param tempo an array to place the merged result
 * @param left the left-most index of the subarray
 * @param right the right-most index of the subarray
 */
private static void mergeSort(Integer[] a, Integer[] tempo, int left, int right)
{
    if(left < right)
    {
        int center = (left + right) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, tempo, left, center);
        mergeSort(a, tempo, center + 1, right);
        merge(a, tempo, left, center + 1, right);
    }
}
```

### Merge Routine

```
/**
 * Internal method that merges two sorted halves of a subarray
 * @param a an array of Comparable items
 * @param tempo an array to place the merged result
 * @param leftpos the left-most index of the subarray
 * @param rightpos the index of the start of the second half
 * @param rightend the right-most index of the subarray
 **/
private static void merge(Integer[] a, Integer[] tempo, 
                               int leftpos, int rightpos, int rightend)
{
    int leftend = rightpos - 1;
    int tempos = leftpos;
    int nbelement = rightend - leftpos + 1;
    
    while(leftpos <= leftend && rightpos <= rightend)
    {
        if(a[leftpos].compareTo(a[rightpos]) <= 0)
        {
            tempo[tempos++] = a[leftpos++];
        }
        else
        {
            tempo[tempos++] = a[rightpos++];
        }
    }
    
    while(leftpos <= leftend)
    {
        tempo[tempos++] = a[leftpos++];
    }
    
    while(rightpos <= rightend)
    {
        tempo[tempos++] = a[rightpos++];
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < nbelement; i++, rightend--)
    {
        a[rightend] = tempo[rightend];
    }
}
```

Source :

Data Structures and algorithm analysis in Java

third Edition

Mark Allen Weiss